# How to add horizontal scrollbar when container and children have width auto?

Tags: css, overflow

My container has the following styling:

```
.timeFrameContainer {
  height: 140px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width:auto;
}
```

and the children inside:

```
.nutrient {
  width: auto;
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

All my containers show up next to eachother untill the full width of the page has been reached. After this the children show up underneath the others.

I want them all to show up next to eachother and show a horizontal scrollbar whenever it exceeds the page width. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the wrapping of inline elements, assign [**`white-space: nowrap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the container:

```css
.timeFrameContainer {
  height: 140px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nutrient {
  width: 120px; /** changed for the demo **/
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red; /** changed for the demo **/
}
```

```html
<div class="timeFrameContainer">
  <div class="nutrient"></div>
  <div class="nutrient"></div>
  <div class="nutrient"></div>
  <div class="nutrient"></div>
  <div class="nutrient"></div>
  <div class="nutrient"></div>
  <div class="nutrient"></div>
  <div class="nutrient"></div>
</div>
```